# Adding a UIImageview to only some custom cells in a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to add a UIImage to only certain cells in a UITableview, but whenever the user scrolls past an image, i end up with a bunch of misplaced imageviews, imageview end up in all the wrong cells and it is just a mess. Thanks for any responses in advance.
code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"sections:%ld", (long)tableView.numberOfSections);
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *message =  self.retreivedMessages[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (long)indexPath.row);
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20000];
    UILabel *messageContent = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10000];
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30000];
    image.tag = indexPath.row;
    UILabel *usernameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:50000];
    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:60000];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapPhoto = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedPhoto:)];
    CGRect imageFrame = image.frame;
    CGPoint imagePoint = imageFrame.origin;
    imagePoint.y = 8;
    image.frame = imageFrame;
    NSLog(@"frameY: %f", imageFrame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"imageFrameOrigin: %f", image.frame.origin.y);
    UIButton *replyButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40000];
    replyButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    messageContent.text = [message objectForKey:@"messageContent"];
    NSString *content = [message objectForKey:@"messageContent"];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]};
    CGRect rect = [messageContent.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(251, MAXFLOAT)
                                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                 attributes:attributes
                                                    context:nil];


    messageContent.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    CGFloat height = ceilf(rect.size.height);

    messageContent.frame = CGRectMake(40, 100, 251, height);
    messageContent.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSLog(@"Message: %@", content);
    UIImageView *photoView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:70000];


    NSLog(@"boolean photo: %@", [message objectForKey:@"hasPhoto"]);
    if ([[message objectForKey:@"hasPhoto"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {

        PFFile *photoFile = [message objectForKey:@"photo"];
    [self addPhotoToCell:cell file:photoFile photoView:photoView];
     [photoView addGestureRecognizer:tapPhoto];

        NSLog(@"added");
    } else {

    }

    NSLog(@"Height:%f", messageContent.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"y: %f", messageContent.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"estimated height: %f", height);
    NSLog(@"imageY: %f", image.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"ID: %@", [message objectForKey:@"ID"]);

    usernameLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"senderSetName"];
    nameLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"senderName"];
    PFFile *photoProfile = [message objectForKey:@"senderPicture"];
    NSData *data = [photoProfile getData];
    UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    image.image = profileImage;
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 27.0;
    image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    self.messageDate = [message objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatDate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd 'at' hh:mm a"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatDate stringFromDate:self.messageDate];
    dateLabel.text = dateString;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's the "photo" view that you only want to appear in certain cases, then I think you want to add some code to the `else` block to hide or remove any photo views from the cell.

The problem is that once you start scrolling around, the table view will begin to reuse some of the cells that have scrolled off screen to populate the new cells that are scrolling into view. If one of those cells had a photo visible (via the true branch of your `if` statement where you are creating a photo view and calling `addPhotoToCell`), then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` might return one of these cells with all of its views intact instead of returning a brand new uninitialized cell. If you end up reusing one of these cells for a message row where `hasPhoto` is not YES, then it looks like you are not doing anything to hide that photo view. Thus, add some code to the `else` block to hide that photo view if it exists.

Comment: I added code to remove the photoview from the cell under else but that just resulted in only the first tableview cell that appeared to have the desired image in it while the others after it did not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line since it will reuse the cells which are freed once the user scrolls. Say if the scrolled up cell has an UIImageView and that cell might be reused(which causes problems in ur case).

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Instead Create a cell every time. It will work great.

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

If that is gonna make ur application slow, use a if else condition to check if the freed up cell has a cellImage and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong.

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1"];

     if (!cell)
     {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"1"];
         UIImageView *cellImage = [UIImageView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 35 , 35)];
         cellImage.tag = 1 ;
         [cellImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];

         [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
     }

     UIImageView*cellImage = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
     [cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ratingFullIcon.png"]];
     return cell;    
}
```

You should alloc UITableViewCell :
All the subviews in UITableViewCell contentView also should be allocated when cell doesnot exists. if it exists we dont need to alloc init.

setText or setImage outside this condition.